# Setting bean property 'jobClass' of org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, quartz-scheduler

My project has a Quartz scheduler and I am setting the JobDetailBean as

```
<bean id="deadlineFailureChecker" class="info.release.scheduler.DeadlineFailureChecker" />

<bean id="workingHourPerDayUpdater" class="info.release.scheduler.WorkingHourPerDayUpdater" />

<bean name="scheduledJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="info.release.scheduler.ScheduledJob" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="deadlineFailureChecker" value-ref="deadlineFailureChecker" />
            <entry key="workingHourPerDayUpdater" value-ref="workingHourPerDayUpdater" />
        </map>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

Now as I want pass a property value to the info.release.scheduler.ScheduledJob I did:

```
<bean id="scheduledJobBean" class="info.release.scheduler.ScheduledJob">
    <property name="afrodite" ref="afrodite" />
</bean>

<bean name="scheduledJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass">
        <bean factory-bean="scheduledJobBean" factory-method="getClass"></bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="deadlineFailureChecker" value-ref="deadlineFailureChecker" />
            <entry key="workingHourPerDayUpdater" value-ref="workingHourPerDayUpdater" />
        </map>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

But the following `System.out.println` is printing `null`:

```
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("============================================="+this.afrodite);

}
```

This method belongs to `info.release.scheduler.ScheduledJob extends QuartzJobBean`.

I also did an experiment, I set

```
<bean id="scheduledJobBean" class="info.release.scheduler.ScheduledJob">
    <property name="afrodite" ref="afrodite" />
</bean>
```

To

```
<bean id="scheduledJobBean" class="info.release.scheduler.ScheduledJob" init-method="init">
    <property name="afrodite" ref="afrodite" />
</bean>
```

and

```
public void init() {
    System.out.println("============================================="+this.afrodite);
}
```

In this init the `System.out.println` isn't printing null rather a value.

I cannot understand what is going on! Is JobDetailBean re-instantiating the jobClass object?

What I need is to set a property of the value-class of the `jobClass` property of `JobDetailBean`.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'd same issue. I ended up with making it private static. make it like as follows

```
private static afrodite;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So the ScheduledJob class is re-instantiate each time?